# Linear Transformation of a Random Variable with a Laplace Distribution

Tags: data-transformation, expected-value, linear, laplace-distribution

I have read these two posts ( [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173163/linear-transformation-of-gaussian-random-variable) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what)) about linear transformation of a random variable with a Gaussian distribution. I would like to find the first two moments of a linearly transformed Laplace distribution and then find the parameters of the new transformed distribution. I would like to know if the steps are the same as of the Gaussian? (I.e. considering the linearity of the expectation and continuing from there.)

Comment: Welcome to CV, samsambakster! This is a decent start of a first question. However, community norms are that questions (and answers) are independent of information contained in hyperlinks. Can you edit your question with a quote from or describe a relevant section or sections from the linked sources, to amplify your question and make it stand on its own without requiring the audience to try to follow links which may rot, not be accessible from all countries, etc.?

Comment: @Alexis Links to threads within this site are perfectly fine: we control them and they won't disappear unexpectedly.  Samsam: by definition, a Laplace distribution is a linear transformation of a Double Exponential distribution.  Since one linear transformation followed by another one is also linear, with easily computed coefficients, there doesn't seem to be anything to do here.

Comment: @whuber Sure. My problem was not with links. I frequently include links in my own Qs & As. My problem was demanding that the audience follow links, identify and interpret the OP's intended part of the linked text (whether on this site or not) whether or not the OP provided explicit guidance as what part that was. My points about link-rot are applicable to external links, but building strong question-writing skills—including making them independent of linked content—benefits the site as a whole, yes?